# Problem with starting a Sound at a specified position (AS2)

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript-2

I have an issue with an Actionscript 2 piece of code. I'm trying to load a song and start playing it at the 50th second until the end.

```
var song:Sound = new Sound();
song.setVolume(100);
song.loadSound(songToPlay,true); // songToPlay is a valid path
song.start(50);
```

This loads and play the Sound, but at the begining and not at 50 seconds like I want. I also tried

```
song.start(50,1);
```

without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to start a sound file at a specific time, you have to start it after it's finished loading (or at least loaded past that point).

Try something like this:

```
var song:Sound = new Sound();
song.setVolume(100);
song.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) 
{
   if (success) 
   {
      song.start(50);
   } 
};
song.loadSound(songToPlay,true);
```

Comment: No problem. Actually I believe you could also just set "false" in your loadSound function, which would essentially have the same effect. (Specifying "true" means that it's a streaming sound and can begin playing as soon as it starts downloading.)