# Play sound in Flash with offset

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript

I am trying to start a soundclip with some offset, but for some reason it always starts at the beginning.

```
var my_sound:Sound = new Sound();
my_sound.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
    if (success) {
        my_sound.start(4);
    }
};

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sound.wav");
my_sound.loadSound(request, true);
```

I have found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217050/problem-with-starting-a-sound-at-a-specified-position-as2), but AFAICT I am already doing that correctly.

So I have no idea why the clip starts playing at the start instead of after 4 seconds.

I am working with AS2 if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it right, it's just not working because the start parameter is measured in milliseconds instead of seconds.

try this:

```
my_sound.start(4000);
```